# ASP.NET Repeater Causing JQuery Image Slider

Tags: asp.net, jquery, repeater

I have a jquery Image slider in a content page that worked fine. Once I converted it into a asp repeater the first image of the repeater would display twice, then run normally.

Any idea on why the repeater is causing this?

I think I discovered that the first image link

```
<ItemTemplate>
 <a href='<%#Eval("Url")%>'>
 <img src='<%#Eval("Image")%>' alt="Spring Break 2011"
  rel='<h3><%#Eval("Title")%></h3><%#Eval("Caption")%>'/></a>
</ItemTemplate>
```

I have to place class="show" in the first item only. Does anyone know how to implement this during the first time it goes through. Hmm

Comment: Considering this isn't typical behavior, the problem is likely something you accidentally overlooked. Can you post your markup and javascript code?

Comment: How about printing the first item separatly, then run the loop over items.Skip(1) or whatever the LINQ-command is?

Comment: I thought about that, but i would rather dynamically add a class

Comment: Hmm. Not shure about that. I guess you don't like the idea of a header-template either, since it's bacisally the same as my idea.... I'm out of ideas. I don't know how much real code you can put inside the item-template (like conditions and stuff). Never used the ASP.NET repeater control. Sorry for beeing so useless :-P

Comment: i use the header template and footer for open and closing of divs but thats it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
<ItemTemplate>
 <a href='<%#Eval("Url")%>' <%# Container.ItemIndex == 0 ? "class='show'" : "" %> >
 <img src='<%#Eval("Image")%>' alt="Spring Break 2011"
  rel='<h3><%#Eval("Title")%></h3><%#Eval("Caption")%>'/></a>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Reference the Container.ItemIndex property for the item being databound to the repeater and if it is 0 (i.e. item 1), output a class attribute.

Comment: You are..AWESOME..mad kudos to you kristian